# break a loop of request-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, request-promise

I'm looping over this url `/api?id=1&page=` every time requesting a different page until i get the result i want.

I can't figure out how and why i can't stop the loop from within the request.

```js
async something() {

  let results = []
  for (let i = 0;i < 999;i++) {
    await rp('/api?id=1page='+i).then(string => {
     results.push(string)
     if(results === 'THE END') {
        // break here
     }
    })
  }
  Promise.all(results).then(res => {
   // do something
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only break from a loop when the loop is *inside* the current function. If the loop is outside the function (eg, a `.then` callback), you can't break out of it.

Instead of using `.then`, assign the `await`ed string to a variable and check it (and make sure to check the *string* against `'THE END'`, not the `results` array):

```
async something() {
  const results = [];
  for (let i = 0;i < 999;i++) {;
    const string = await rp('/api?id=1page='+i);
    results.push(string);
    if(string === 'THE END') {
      break;
    }
  }
  // do something with results
}
```

Note that since you're pushing the *resolved values themselves* to the `results` array, there's no need to call `Promise.all` on the array.

Comment: that does the job, such a simple solution i feel dumb now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

considering that `rp` is the function that request your url, this is the simplest answer i can come up with.

```js
let results = []
  for (let i = 0;i < 999;i++) {//if i is greater than or equal 999, the loop will end
    await rp('/api?id=1page='+i).then(string => {
     results.push(string)
     if(results === 'THE END') {
        //do stuffs you need to do
        // break here
        i = 1000;
     }
    })
  }
```